# Phonetic symbol - superscript h in Which

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, dictionaries, ipa

**Q1)** What is the meaning of the small **h** (superscript h) in the phonetic symbols of **which** shown in [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/which)?

[image]

> ʰwɪ̠tʃ

1. the small h means 'complete silence' (= just ignore h)
2. the small h means 'pronounce it but very weakly'
3. the small h means 'pronounce it a little weakly'

**Q2)** Is there a similar case other than h?
(a superscript alphabet in the phonetic symbols of a certain word)

I've searched **knife** but there is no superscript **k** in the phonetic symbols.

Comment: In careful, correct English (British English, at least - see [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZmqJQ-nc_s)), **wh** at the beginning of a word is pronounced like **hw**. I notice that the speaker in the audio doesn't actually do so - as most people don't unless, for example, they want to distinguish between _Wales_ and _whales_.

Comment: @KateBunting in 71 years of speaking English (I'm 72 but most of us don't speak until we're 12 months old at least) I've never realised that the 'wh' sound is actually pronounced with the sounds the opposite way round. Isn't that odd?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything to add to a [comprehensive Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet)

Comment: Thank you, "Superscript IPA letters may be used to indicate secondary articulation, releases and other transitions, shades of sound, epenthetic and incompletely articulated sounds"

Comment: But, it is still vague at least for me. What is the ultimate meaning of superscript h..?

Comment: Most of the wh- question words come from Old English versions starting hw-, in this case *where* was [*hwelc*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hwelc) and there a residue of this in the pronounciation

Comment: Read the dictionary's pronunciation guide and all your questions will be answered. https://blog.collinsdictionary.com/ipa-pronunciation-guide-cobuild/

Comment: Thank you, in fact it was the first time I  thought about pronunciation. Now I feel my question was not very good,